# RHEL5 rSync Mysql server

Tags: mysql, linux, rsync

Objective: to be able to synchronize 2 linux server realtime.

My concern is after using Rsync to mirror the mysql server. The only thing it wasnt able to synchronize is the entries (ie. inserting data to the database  using the insert query). How will I be able to solve this?

Things I've done:

- `scp` the keys of the 2 server so that password wont be asked for each transaction
- I used

  ```
  rsync -avc /var/lib/mysql/ root@10.1.99.XXX:/var/lib/mysql/
  ```

  to sync the database/tables, but wasn't able to sync the entries.

Answer (score 0):

Isubaki,

It's not quite as simple as just using rsync, as mysql may have the files open at the time you are pushing them across. Linux will do the file copy ok, but using this technique, the table is locked in memory until the database is restarted.

I do have a script that will do the sync part, but it does require a database restart, which may not be what you want (you mention realtime sync)